# Playing Video in Android's media player from an URL

Tags: android, url, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that plays a video file from an URL that is the IP of a local server. The video plays fine when I run it in a browser or VLC player. But I don't want the IP address to be displayed when I play the video. Is there any way I can accomplish this?
This is the code that plays the video file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



 public class welcome extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);{
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.4/videotest/Camera1.mp4"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }});


        }

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try creating a WebView in your app and play it inside the app? Otherwise you will have to create a public domain and share the video from there

Comment: You are using Intent to invoke third party application which is capable of playing video. If you you want to hide the url and play inside your application you can use videoview control of android. You can find the tutorial in the following link http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html

Comment: I don't want to use a public domain as web servers are not usually available for free and I would just like to hide the URL for now.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a VideoView but if you really want to run it inside a "browser" (webview) you can do something like this.

WebView intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

WebViewActivity

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.4/videotest/Camera1.mp4");

    }
}
```

Layout

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: I tried with that code, but the app takes me to the browser where I get the error for **Web page not found or is been moved permanently**. Do I need to set some permissions specially for using WebView?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I have already added the INTERNET permission, but it now shows just a blank screen for the next Activity.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. You can try putting google in that URL if you want. Are you sure you named the layout correctly inside setContentView?

Comment: Yes, I checked the layout. Its correct. Thanks for your inputs and let me know if you can think of something that can fix this up.